# Problem with sending a Webservice a List Of Objects .Net

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

I have a web service that looks like this

```
    [WebMethod]
    public int Import(System.Collections.Generic.List<Record> importRecords)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (importRecords != null && importRecords.Count > 1)
        {
            DataLayer datalayer = new DataLayer();
            foreach (Record brec in importRecords)
                if (rec != null) 
                {
                    datalayer.InsertUpdateRecord(rec);
                    count++;
                }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

And i have a client software that wants to send data to the web service using this method

```
 ImportService.BVRImportService importService = new ImportService.ImportService();
 ImportService.Record myRecord = new ImportService.Record();
 myRecord.FirstName = "Adam";
 System.Collections.Generic.List<ImportService.Record> myRecords = 
     new List<ImportService.Record>();
 myRecords.Add(myRecord);
 importService.ImportData(myRecords);
```

I keep getting this message when I try to compile the client software.

```
    Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'ImportTask.ImportService.ImportService.ImportData(ImportTask.ImportService.Record[])' has some invalid arguments
Error   2   Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ImportTask.ImportService.Record>' to 'ImportTask.ImportService.BVRRecord[]'
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the reference the client has contains an Record[] instead of a `List<Record>`.  You can fix this by calling the .ToArray method on the `List<Record>`.

```
importService.ImportData(myRecords.ToArray());
```

I'm also confused by the use of Record in code but BVRRecord in the error messages.  Are you changing the type names in your solution or are there actually 2 different types?  If it's the latter you'll also need to convert to the BVRRecord type before calling ImportData.

Comment: i copied that error message before i changed it the object to Record. it still did the same thing. But your solution solved the error.

Comment: You can also fix this by clicking the "Advanced" button on the "Add Service Reference" dialog and setting to use Generic List for collections instead of array.